# ImageProvide Class in FOP Apache

Tags: apache-fop

while generating pdf which contain image logo.gif with FOP getting error

```
Error while loading image (Jimi): com/sun/jimi/core/Jimi
```

when i generate pdf with FOP source i come to know that ImageProvider class,
if ImageProvider class is JAIImage not getting any error but when JIMIImage class available then getting error because it is calling function **Jimi.getImageProducer** which is in jimi.jar file path **com.sun.jimi.core.Jimi**.

can any one please tell on what bases the ImageProvider Class is get selected in FOP while generating pdf which contain image.

Comment: Which version of FOP are you using? Which version of Java?

Comment: FOP-0.94 and java 1.7

Comment: Is the JIMI jar in the classpath? Later versions of FOP, starting with 0.95, [no longer use JAI and JIMI](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/graphics.html#introduction); using a more recent FOP version (if it's feasible for you) *could* resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion,i have not kept jimi jar in my class path,so it is throwing error.